# Can't get the keys in a database to parse as part of an array

Tags: php, arrays, database, dictionary

I have an table in my database which so far has been great for storing stuff in more than one object. But i want to be able to transform it into a multi-object array thingy.

Here is the data which is related to this new 'object' (in mysql):

```
    uid     field              value
    page:1  shop[2].location    In Shops, Dundas Arcades,Middlesbrough, TS1 1HT
    page:1  shop[1].location    5a High Street, Stockton-on-tees, TS18 1UB
    page:1  name                Enter The Asylum
    page:1  contact.website     http://entertheasylum.co.uk
    page:1  contact.phone       0800 090 090
```

Now what i'm looking for is to via PHP transform it into something like (print_r output):

```
array(
   "name" => "Enter The Asylum",
   "shop" => array(
      array("location" => "In Shops, Dundas Arcades..."),
      array("location" => "5a High Street, Stockton-on-tees...")
   ),
   "contact" => array(
      "website" => "http://entertheasylum.co.uk",
      "phone" => "0800 090 090"
   )
 )
```

anybody got any ideas?

Comment: That's a good example how to *not* use relational databases. :)

Comment: On my current setup it's all I can use... i've got no ideas on how to do this...

Comment: I've got to ask, how was it "great" in the past? You're breaking almost all normal form. That said, you may be able to use variable variables in PHP to solve your problem. I'm not positive though.

Comment: well it was because it was fine as one array (like name, date of birth etc) now I'm wanting to add arrays and stuff, but I don't want to loose compatibility with mysql and stuff

Comment: Can you tell us about your current setup, and why you can't normalize this? Are you unable to create new tables?

Comment: i am able to create new tables but I don't know if mysql natively allows me to do this anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do this via regex and php. Here is the magic function (it's part of my code and stuff):

```
function fetch_profile_info($id){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM profile_info WHERE `uid`='".me($id)."'";
    $r = mysql_query($sql);
    $profile = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)){
        /* new: process it into objects etc */
        $field = $row['field'];
        $field = preg_replace('/\.([a-zA-Z]*)/i', "['$1']", $field);
        $field = preg_replace('/^([a-zA-Z]*)/', "['$1']", $field);
        eval("\$profile{$field} = \"".addslashes($row['value'])."\";");
    }
    return $profile;
}
```

it works! yay!

Comment: "If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question." -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP

Comment: well it's required in this code because there is no other way i could get this to work... why is eval() in there anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the original problem, but I'll suggest a proper way to use relational databases like MySQL. That is, you tables should have a structure like this:

**Table page:**

- id **PK**
- name
- phone
- website

**Table page_location:**

- id **PK** *(this is technically not necessary, but nicer than having a primary key on position)*
- page_id **FK** *(references page.id)*
- position
- location

Data would then look something like this.

**Table page:**

```
| id | name               | phone          | website                       |
| 1  | "Enter The Asylum" | "0800 090 090" | "http://entertheasylum.co.uk" |
```

**Table page_position:**

```
| id | page_id | position | location                                          |
| 1  | 1       | 1        | "5a High Street, Stockton-on-tees, TS18 1UB"      |
| 2  | 1       | 2        | "In Shops, Dundas Arcades,Middlesbrough, TS1 1HT" |
```

And some additional reading: [Relational model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model)

Comment: that's no good as I want to be able to easily via the code dynamically add new parts (they'll be a lot more in the database, each with different items etc)

Comment: @jos Simpson: You would be surprised how powerful this kind of setup is. Unless you are building some sort of CMS (Where the ability of users to define new information is vast) This is probably the way to go. Especially if you expect to be able to easily translate the DB Information to a format that you can use.

Comment: i don't want like 1000 tables just for these objects... i've figured it out with some lovely regex :)